# Laravel pre-populate database field in code - best way?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

In my use case I have user-entered data, shown as rows in a table, say items with a monetary value. A good example would be cars each with a retail value. I then give the user an additional column to enter their own adjusted values so that they can see the sum of their adjusted values beside the sum of the original values for comparison. I then store the tweaked value for each row as a JSON field to record tweaked values and proposal names.

[image]

I want to start the adjust column with the original value data, and then if the user makes changes, store that value or the original value if unchanged. My question is, how do I initially populate the adjustment database fields with the original value so that before they make any changes the values shown/stored are the same as the original value. I'm thinking in terms of the user clicking a "new proposal" button, they name the proposal and then see the list of items with the original value and an adjustment field already with the original value ready to tweak. Then I save their adjustment data.

Do I need to run a loop in my controller (or blade) to pre-populate the database fields before I display them? I'd like to add the new proposal name and value to each item in the database before loading the blade. That way the blade shows the default unchanged set, but can also save the adjustments if made.

Hope this makes sense. Any ideas or advice is very welcome.

I'm using Laravel 5.5 with XAMPP with MariaDB 10.2 (for JSON field support)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any purpose to populate it in the database. Just show it as a an input with pre-populated value:

```
<td>{{ $model->value }}</td>
<td><input name="adjusted_value" value="{{ $model->value }}"></td>
```

in a loop. Then process is after the form is submitted.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm using x-editable elements to edit the adjustment value in-place, so (although I'll test pre-populating the adjust field in the blade markup) I think the x-editable field needs to read/write directly to the database, so I'm not sure if setting the value in my blade markup will store that value if the user doesn't modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to populate both databases when the original data database is created/inserted to.

So if youre inserting to table A that holds the "real" data
Make sure you insert the same value to table B that holds the "user" modified data

Although as as @Laraleg said, you dont really need to prepopulate another table. Just output the same value from table A into the input field

Comment: @ Marina, since the user can name and save many proposals (full value sets) for the items I'm using JSON to store those values as an array (two elements, the proposal name and value for the item in that proposal) with each item and therefore its not a one-time dupe of the original data entry when the user inserts the original data.

Comment: Im a bit confused since theres no real example provided, but if youre doing arrays you could json_encode the data into your database. Just make sure you take into consideration that it will make it near impossible to search through that database with simple mysql. If so, initialize the array to something like ['original' => 1000, 'user' => null] and serialize it or something

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure it can help or not but I'm sure you will get Idea how you can use it.

```
{{Form::text('name', (
    old('name') ? old('name') : ( 
        isset($database_entity->name) ? $database_entity->name : (
            isset($default_holder) ? $default_holder : NULL
        )
    )
) ,['class'=>'whatever'] )}}
```

Here I took text field Used [Laravel collective](https://laravelcollective.com/). I checked condition if value is hint by **old** function (when validation false) it will set from old. If there are no value in Old function then from database modal in case if you are using edit or update.

Last if nothing from both of them then it will set your value or you can say pre-populate variable.

Good Luck !!